# BigQuery / Airflow - Cannot create partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm using the `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator` within Airflow to create tables in my BigQuery project. It's been working great, for everything except partitioned tables.

When I try to pass the required dictionary ([specified here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#TimePartitioning)) to the `time_partitioning` parameter, I get the following completely nonsensical error message:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/MY_PROJECT/datasets/MY_DATASET/tables?prettyPrint=false: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "timePartitioning" at 'table': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list
```

I literally have no idea where to even start with debugging this. Here is the exact operator code. It works just fine if `time_partitioning` is not passed.

```
create = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
   task_id="create",
   bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud',
   project_id="MY_PROJECT",
   dataset_id="MY_DATASET",
   table_id=table_name,
   schema_fields=self.get_schema(),
   time_partitioning={'field': 'ds', 'type' : 'DAY'},
)
```

Comment: hope you have given `table_id="table_name"` (table_name in quotes) and try removing the comma `,` after the last field

Comment: What is the output of this function: `get_schema()`? Also please share your version of: `apache-airflow-providers-google`

Comment: Hi @SeeBeeOss, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I used the below sample code to run dag’s which uses `BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator` and `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator` to create dataset and partitioned table with the time_partitioning parameter in BigQuery.

```
import os
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator,
    BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator,
)

from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "your-project-id")
DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME", "testdataset")

TABLE_NAME = "partitioned_table"

SCHEMA = [
    {"name": "value", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "ds", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
]

dag_id = "example_bigquery"


with models.DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval="@hourly",  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    tags=["example"],
    user_defined_macros={"DATASET": DATASET_NAME, "TABLE": TABLE_NAME},
    default_args={"project_id": PROJECT_ID},
) as dag_with_locations:
    create_dataset = BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator(
        task_id="create-dataset", dataset_id=DATASET_NAME, project_id=PROJECT_ID
    )
    create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id="create_table",
        dataset_id=DATASET_NAME,
        table_id=TABLE_NAME,
        schema_fields=SCHEMA,
        time_partitioning={
            "type": "DAY",
            "field": "ds",
        },
    )
    
    create_dataset >> create_table
```

**Output:**

[image]